# Complex analysis textbooks adopting the Weierstrass approach

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I want to read an (upper-undergraduate or beginning graduate level) complex analysis textbook that develops the theory mostly by means of power series.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Henri Cartan's complex analysis text starts off with power series. From the preface: *"In the first place I decided to begin by offering not Cauchy's point
of view (differentiable functions and Cauchy's integral) but the Weierstrass
point of view, i.e. the theory of convergent power series (chapter 1)."*

Comment: All complex analysis texts that I recall take what the comment above calls Cauchy's approach. If you haven't studied complex analysis before, it is worth studying from standard modern texts anyway, because they are probably better written. Once you have done so, you will understand complex power series much better, and you can then more easily answer the question of how the theory of complex analysis would be built up were you to start from the notion of a power series.

Comment: @ChrisSanders It’s my first time studying complex analysis. The power series approach somehow seems to be more natural, so I think I’ll be learning both approaches simultaneously

Comment: Books by [Konrad Knopp](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Knopp/) seem like good prospects.

Comment: I suggest Beardon's *Complex Analysis: The Argument Principle in Analysis and Topology*.  It was released as a Dover 2 years ago.  For that matter sole the review of it on Amazon is quite good and lists several other books that also take the Weierstrass approach:  Cartan, Lang and Marshall (released in 2019 so qualifies as a "modern" book I infer)

Comment: @user8675309 thanks for introducing Beardon’s book, after going through a brief description of the book I realized that I should read this book to learn the Weierstrass approach